# Stalling time for all requests only on chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

I recently started working on improving the speed of a company online system
the first thing i noticed was that every request get a stalling time of 150-200 ms, and since the system is kinda poorly built with a lot of use of iframes a page that require 20 resources get a 4 sec delay because of this stalling alone.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7IlQ.png)

I got no idea what is causing this so any help would be appreciated.

some information that might help:

- this behavior only happen in chrome no such delays can be seen on
  firefox for example.
- the system is built using asp.net C#.
- the system is hosted in Germany and we are connecting to it from Israel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update so this question don't remain unanswered.

The problem was the developers who originally wrote the code sat the pressitentCookie to false so on chrome it had to go through establishing a new connection for every single resource while firefox kinda ignored it. 
that plus chrome limit to load 5 resources at a time made each request take way longer than other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You are using devexpress somewhere in that page.... and I believe that might be an issue. Give a try also in here: "https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/List/1"

Other noticeable aspect: where are caching of of all those .js, .css, etc static files??? Take a look on that...